# Object oriented EDI handling in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, object-oriented

I'm currently starting a new sub project where I will:

1. Retrieve the order information from our mainframe
2. Save the order information to our web-apps' database
3. Send the order as [EDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) (either D01b or D93a)
4. Receive the order response, despatch advice and invoice messages
5. Do all kinds of fun things with the resulting datasets.

However I am struggling with my initial class designs.

The order information will be retrieved from the mainframe which will result in a "AOrder" class, this isn't a problem, I am not sure about how to mold this local object into an EDI string.

Should I create EDIOrder/EDIOrderResponse/etc classes with matching decorators (EDIOrderD01BDecorator, EDIOrderD93ADecorator)? Do I need builder objects or can I do:

```
// $myOrder is instance of AOrder
$myOrder->toEDIOrder();
$decorator = new EDIOrderD01BDecorator($myOrder);
$edi = $decorator->getEDIString();
```

And it'll have to work the other way around as well. Is the following code a good way of handling this problem or should I go about this differently?

```
$ediString = $myEDIMessageBroker->fetch();
$ediOrderResponse = EDIOrderResponse::fromString($ediString);
```

I'm just not so sure about how I should go about designing the classes and interactions between them.

Thanks for reading and helping.

Answer (score 1):

If the only point of the EDIOrderD01BDecorator is to produce an EDI String, then I would create a EDIOrderSerialization class with static methods to deserialize and serialize in the various necessary formats.

Elsewise if there is further processing to do with an EDIOrder object instead of AOrder, then I would go with the decorator pattern.